# Ocupar solicitudes Ajax en mas de un select clonado laravel 5

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

Tengo una tabla en la cual agrego filas con jquery. Éstas filas tienen varios inputs y un select. La funcionalidad del select es que al momento de elegir un producto, en un input se muestre su descripción, esto funciona bien con una llamada $.get de ajax. El problema es el siguiente: Cuando agrego otra fila en mi tabla (td) y quiero elegir mi producto con el select, el input no me muestra su descripción, entonces quería saber que es lo que debo hacer para que me pueda mostrar eso. Necesito volver a llamar la solicitud ajax?
Si pueden guiarme por favor lo agradecería bastante.

Script de agregar un fila

```
$("#addRow").on("click",function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();    

    $("#tabla tr:last").clone().find("input, select").val('').each(function() {  }).end().appendTo("#tabla");

});
```

Script del ajax

```
$("#mmscod_id").on("change", function(){

    var select = $('#mmscod_id option:selected').val(); 
    var select2 = $('#mmscod_id option:selected').text();  

    $.get("/product/"+select+"/"+select2,function(response){  
        $('#descripcion').val(response);   
    });

});
```

Adjunto imagen del problema 
[image: Vista]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay dos problemas en el código de arriba:

1. Tienes IDs duplicados: cuando duplicas una fila, estás duplicando los campos dentro de esa fila incluídos sus IDs. Aunque esto no tiene por qué ser directamente lo que causa el problema, puede generarte problemas con los selectores. Deberías usar clases en lugar de IDs.
2. Si estás asociando la acción que realiza la llamada AJAX al inicio de la página, entonces sólo se asociará a los elementos que estén ya creados (la primera fila) pero no a los que se creen nuevos (fila 2, 3, 4...). Para solucionar este problema tienes dos opciones:

   1. Clonar incluyendo los eventos haciendo `clone(true)`, pero entonces te encontrarás con el problema descrito en el paso 1: los eventos se asociarán, pero, como tienes IDs duplicados, no se realizarán sobre los elementos que esperas.
   2. Usar `on` pero con eventos delegados. Esto hace que los eventos se asocien a los elementos cuando estos se creen en la página.

Para delegar los eventos podrías hacer algo como esto (cambiando el ID por una clase):

```
$("body").on("change", ".mmscod_id", function(){

    $this = $(this);

    var select = $this.find('option:selected').val(); 
    var select2 = $this.find('option:selected').text();  

    $.get("/product/"+select+"/"+select2,function(response){  
        $this.closest("tr").find('.descripcion').val(response);   
    });

});
```

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo parecido, pero cambiando los IDs por clases, y sin hacer la llamada AJAX, sólo mostrando la URL que se llamaría por la consola y en el campo de texto de la misma fila:

```js
$("#addRow").on("click",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();    
  $("#tabla tr:last").clone().find("input, select").val('').each(function() {  }).end().appendTo("#tabla");
})

$("#tabla").on("change", ".mmscod_id", function(){
  
  $this = $(this);
  
  var select = $this.find('option:selected').val(); 
  var select2 = $this.find('option:selected').text();  

  console.log("/product/"+select+"/"+select2);
  $this.closest("tr").find('.descripcion').val("/product/"+select+"/"+select2);   
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="addRow">Click Me</button>
</div>
<table id="tabla">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="mmscod_id">
        <option value="1">Uno</option>
        <option value="2">Dos</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="" class="descripcion" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Alvaro Montoro, funcionó muy bien.
Agradecido de tu respuesta y ayuda.